# Difference between git config push.default and git push origin HEAD

Tags: git, git-push

I have read about how we can configure our git push to push to the current branch we are in using
1.

`git config push.default current`

but I also read about how you can push to your remote branch (to have the same name as your local branch) using
2.

`git push origin HEAD`

When do you use 1 and when do you use 2?

Comment: 1. is sets a configuration 2. pushes changes. apples and oranges.

Comment: @knittl: well, apples and "fruit in general" sometimes perhaps: `git push origin HEAD` supplies enough arguments that `git push` *ignores* the configured setting, but `git push` without the `origin HEAD` part *uses* the configured setting, so there's some cross-over at some point—just not in the question as phrased...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `git config push.default current`, then you can later just do `git push`. When you do `git push origin HEAD`, you are explicitly pushing to the `HEAD` commit to the `origin` remote.

p.s. You should use a branch name instead of `HEAD`.

Comment: It's OK to use `HEAD` here: Git will resolve it to a branch name. If it resolves to a raw hash ID (due to being in detached-HEAD) mode, the `git push` operation will fail. If you mean "should" as in "that's my preferred practice", disregard this comment. :-)

Comment: @torek Thanks for the clarification. I didn't know using `HEAD` would even work here.